# Stupidedi Either.failure("segment ST~ does not occur")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, rubygems, edi

I'm using Ruby library STUPIDEDI to parse some X12 Files. I am not getting beyond this error in the title. Please help me

Code

```
    input  = if RUBY_VERSION > "1.8"
           File.open(Rails.root.join('spec','fixtures','22.txt'), :encoding => "ISO-8859-1")
         else
            File.open(Rails.root.join('spec','fixtures','22.txt'))
         end
p input
config = Stupidedi::Config.hipaa
parser = Stupidedi::Parser.build(config)
parser, result = parser.read(Stupidedi::Reader.build(input))
if result.fatal?
    result.explain{|reason| raise reason + " at #{result.position.inspect}" }
end
x = parser.first
  .flatmap{|m| m.find(:GS) }
  .flatmap{|m| m.find(:ST) }
  .tap do |m|
    el(m.find(:N1, "PR"), 2){|e| puts "Payer: #{e}" }
    el(m.find(:N1, "PE"), 2){|e| puts "Payee: #{e}" }
  end
p x
input.close
```

File

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*CHEESE         *12*VENDOR ISA*160321*1828*U*00400*000004970*0*T*>~
GS*PS*CHEESE*2018584966*20160321*1828*4970*X*004010~
ST*830*0001~
BFR*00*Forecast ID**DL*A*20131229*20140323*20140104****MN~
REF*IA*Vendor Code~
N1*DU*CHEESE US*15*1526642~
N1*VN*Vendor Name*92*123456789~
LIN*1*UP*123456789123456*B123456789~
UIT*EA~
FST*0*D*W*20131229~
FST*0*D*W*20140105~
FST*0*D*W*20140112~
FST*0*D*W*20140119~
FST*0*D*W*20140126~
FST*0*D*W*20140202~
FST*0*D*W*20140209~
FST*0*D*W*20140216~
FST*0*D*W*20140223~
FST*0*D*W*20140302~
FST*0*D*W*20140309~
FST*0*D*W*20140316~
FST*0*D*W*20140323~
SE*21*0001~
GE*1*4970~
IEA*1*000004970~
```

Please help me how to solve this. I really need your help! I am new to EDI

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the stack trace.

Comment: @JaredBeck but it was the only error that occurs from the stack trace

Comment: Turns out     Stupidedi::Config.contrib(Stupidedi::Config.hipaa(Stupidedi::Config.default)) solved  the problem. For anyone who would use , stupidedi! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this solved the problem: `Stupidedi::Config.contrib(Stupidedi::Config.hipaa(Stupidedi::Config.default))`

For anyone who would use, stupidedi!